# Editing code on local machine not shared with docker httpd container

Tags: php, docker, apache, docker-compose, docker-container

I had edited a docker-compose.yml for my dockerized php application.
Bellow is the content of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  httpd:
    image: httpd:latest
    ports:
        - "80:80"   # Default Apache port (Default on PHP 7.4)
        - "8073:8073" # PHP 7.3 Apache port
        - "8074:8074" # PHP 7.4 Apache port
        - "8081:8081" # PHP 8.1 Apache port
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html/myApp/:rw
        - ./dev/Docker/httpd/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: httpd
    networks:
      - mb-frontend
```

Code is shared between my host machine and the container as you see. But when i edit my code on the host machine, the code on the container isn't synchronized.
To see if there is changes on the container, I had copied the edited file from the container to my local machine. There is no changes. Code on the container and the host machine aren't the same (Different). Help please!!

Comment: Try using `:cached` instead of `:rw` on your volume. Also try removing the trailing slash after `myApp` , I recall Docker having trouble with that in the past.

Comment: @RobRuchte I tried to change :rw by :cached and i had eliminated slashs but I have usually the same problem

Comment: It seems like docker-compose is loading images from cache. When i commented some images on docker-compose.yml and i run 'docker-compose up' : the commented image is up